# PHP/mySQL - how to encode/decode/escape/whatever needed strings safely before inserting on database

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is this: I have a database where all fields are VARCHAR. Some represent html code. This code contains chars like ◉, ⬛︎, ◔, ➜, ★, ✦, etc. These characters are not encoded on the HTML. They are like you see them here.

Other fields on that database are URLs.

I know I have to escape these chars to prevent sql-injection and also have to encode them to allow insertion on the database.

`htmlspecialchars` will not handle these symbols because they are not encoded on the source. `mysql_escape_string` will only escape bars and double quotes, etc.

How do I really encode this and escape in `PHP` so I can insert this data on the database and how do I read them back?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parameterized queries` to prevent `SQL` injection. And use `htmlspecialchars()` function when you display data in html. With PDO that I love:

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_password);
$query = 'INSERT INTO table (data1, data2) VALUES (:data1, :data2)';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);                          
$statement->bindValue(':data1',$data1);
$statement->bindValue(':data2',$data2)
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found same problem when i insert German string value into varchar type field, string are converted to unreadable characters.

This is the problem of UTF-8, I solve this issue by following thing:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

I hope it will fix your problem in every fields of your DB.

Answer (score -3):

if you are trying to remove all characters beside regular a-z letters and 0-9 numbers use preg_match:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $value);
```

Comment: thats not what he is asking